# How do I prevent duplicate rows from getting inserted?

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard, concurrent-programming

I apologize for the vague question, but I don't know how to put this in one sentence. That is why I could not even try to Google this out.

I have a DropWizard resource and I used Hibernate to access my DB. I have the following entities with their attributes.

```
Trip
====
id
from_place
to_place
time
user_who_booked_it
trip_group_ref

TripGroup
=========
id
from_place
to_place
time
```

`TripGroup` basically groups all trips which have same from, to places and time. That is later helpful in some other tasks.

The resource which creates the `Trip` object first needs to check if a matching `TripGroup` exists, if not then it creates one. This poses a problem. If there are concurrent requests then it is possible that two of more `TripGroup` instances with exact same parameters might get created.

How do I solve this?

One possible solution could be that I wrap the portion of the code which checks and creates these objects inside a `synchronized` block. However, maybe that won't work since the commit will be fired after the resource's method completes, that is, outside the `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 0):

The duplication constraints should really be set at the Database level. Even if you can handle all the concurrency issues in your application code, there is nothing stopping a DB client inserting a duplicate TripGroup row directly into your table.

In Dropwizard, if you are using `Hibernate`, you can annotate your TripGroup model class with something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip_group", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id", "fromPlace", "toPlace", "time"}))
public class TripGroup
```

This will create a constraint in your DB and you will get a error when it is violated. If you are using `JDBI` then you'll need to handcraft your table creation or use `Liquibase`.

Comment: There is a problem there. Yes this will prevent the issue, however, the user will get a 500 error. How do I catch it and retry?

Comment: If you have a duplicate that is a constraint violation, it wouldn't make sense to retry with the exact same parameters. Not sure if I understood your use case.

Comment: When the constraint violation error occurs then DropWizard logs that and sends a 500 error back to client. My question is, is it possible that DropWizard instead of doing that retry one more time, calling the same resource again with the same params?

Comment: The best way to handle this would be to catch the exception and respond with a 422 status because an entity with that unique field already exists.